# AWS Extract Volume AttachmentID Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I need to produce a list of all ebs volumes and instance attachments in my account. I understand how to do this will cli but I'd like to use Python. How can I extract the attachment ID for all in-use volumes in my account?

```
    # Get all in-use volumes in all regions  
    result = ec2.describe_volumes( Filters=[{'Name': 'status', 'Values': ['in-use']}])
    for volume in result['Volumes']:
        attachment = ec2.describe_volumes().get('AttachmentsID,[]')
        print(attachment)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`describe_volumes()` already returns the information you need in `'Attachments'`. To print all volumes, you will need to query all regions and handle pagination.

```
import boto3
import botocore.exceptions

session = boto3.Session()
for region in session.get_available_regions('ec2'):
    print(region)
    try:
        ec2 = session.client('ec2', region_name=region)
        for res in ec2.get_paginator('describe_volumes').paginate(Filters=[{'Name': 'status', 'Values': ['in-use']}]):
            for volume in res['Volumes']:
                for attachment in volume['Attachments']:
                    print(attachment['InstanceId'], attachment['VolumeId'])
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'AuthFailure':
            print('No access to', region)
        else:
            raise
```